# correlation between two scales with different numbers of response categories

Tags: r, correlation

Which method can be used to calculate the correlation between two scales (Likert scales) with different numbers of response categories ?
e.g korrelation between scale1 (5-point Likert-scale) vs Scale2 (7-point Likert-scale))
How can this be calculated using RStudio ?

Comment: See [Correlation between different Likert scales](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158899/correlation-between-different-likert-scales)

Comment: The question in the attached post refers to scales with the same number of answer options per scale. But how do i proceed if there are different numbers of answer options to choose from in the two scales to be compared ?

Comment: I don‘t understand the problem. Leaving the question aside if a likert scale could or should be treated as a continuous variable, why don‘t you simply calculate the correlation between your two variables? E.g. Pearson‘s correlation. Check the help with: `?cor`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.